# When printing from Crystal Report Viewer extraeneous headers and footers are printing

Tags: visual-studio-2008, printing, crystal-reports, report

When printing a report in my Visual Studio 2008 web application the Crystal Report Viewer is printing the word CrystalReportViewer in the upper left hand of the report. The url of the report viewer page is in the upper right hand of the report. Page N of N is in the lower left hand of the report and the print date and time is in the lower right. Basically I don't want these header and footer lines at all. Is there an option which will remove them?

Answer (score 0):

forget this. not a problem. the extraneous header and footer was actually caused by new version of firefox defaults. I went into th page setup - margins/headers and footers tab and set them all to blank. this got it back to what it should be.